# How to run JM reference software using visual studio 2010

Tags: h.264

I have downloaded the H.264 source code and I can view it in Visual studio 2010. I don't know how to run the JM Reference software. How can I do that, and how to view the output?

Answer (score 1):

First of all right click on the project in VS and rebuild solution.
After that from command prompt go to  bin folder of JM reference software.
Which is in JM->bin.
Now write lencod.exe in command prompt.
This will run your encoder for default video file selected in encoder configurations. And same goes for decoder that is ldecod.exe.
For other encoding/decoding parameters read manual.
 [These slides will also help you to get started.](http://www.slideshare.net/sodhanipranav/jm-guide)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I recommend you to download the latest JM reference software for H.264/AVC form this [link](http://iphome.hhi.de/suehring/tml/download/). After downloading just click on jm_vc11.sln file (solution file) and it will open in Microsoft Visual Studio (MVS) as this:
[Solution Explorer Image in MVS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoZj3.png)
Then from toolbar menu, click on Build>Batch Build and you will see something like this:
[Batch Build in MVS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVUaD.png)
Then click on Rebuild button and it will compile and build all of the projects of this solution in your current folder. After seconds or so, you can go through a folder called "bin" in the current folder. In this folder you see lots of config files which are in .cfg format. Please open encoder.cfg file and you can see all the encoder configuration for you H.264 codec and at first lines of it there is InputFile name, FramesToBeEncoded, FrameRates and the deafult values is as [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQyAE.png). Just please make sure the file "foreman_part_qcif.yuv" existed in the bin folder. Then just open command prompt (type cmd in windows search bar) and go to the current directory>bin folder where you can see lencod.exe file. Type this in your command line: "lencod.exe -d encoder.cfg" and it will encode your InputFile and generate test_ref.yuv as a reconstruction file that you can see the result of your encoding process. Also you can see your .yuv files using third-party apps like "yuvplayer". For decoding, Please open bin>decoder.cfg and check that the inpuFile is "test.264" and the output is "test_dec.yuv". Then in command prompt type: "ldecod.exe -d decoder.cfg" and the decoded output file will be generated as "test_dec.yuv" which you can play it in yuvplayer, for example. 
For more details about the parameters of encoders and decoders please check the documentation file in your currnet directory>doc folder.